# How does StencilJS lazy loading work in detail?

Tags: lazy-loading, web-component, stenciljs

StencilJS provides a very concise and useful API for creating Custom Elements. That's why a project of mine is using a monorepo containing multiple separately versioned StencilJS projects.

Now, a consumer could use these packages simultaneously, which means the distribution type "dist" (https://stenciljs.com/docs/distribution#importing-the-dist-library-using-a-bundler) would require me to use multiple .esm.js files on the page.

What i am asking myself is - am i sacrificing my customers performance with my approach.

This is why i would like to dive into how lazy loading in stencil is implemented, especially towards the perspective of using multiple bundles in one website

My intuitive guess would be that every bundle generates an instance of a Mutation Observer (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but as of now, i didn't find the corresponding sources in the official repo.

My second guess would be some magic within the CustomElement Class given through the stencil compiler.

I appreciate the support and best regards.
Mysterie